# Sanders Stands Alone

Tags: headlinese

I have a question about the meaning of "*stand alone*" in this [NY Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2016/02/29/us/politics/bernie-sanders-stands-alone-as-hillary-clinton-gains-senate-endorsements.html) headline:

> Bernie Sanders ***Stands Alone*** as Hillary Clinton Gains Senate Endorsements

Definition 1 for "*stand alone*" in this [dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stand-alone?q=stand+alone) reads:

> be unequaled

So, the NY Times headline means that Sanders is unequaled when Clinton gets endorsements?

Comment: Why are you interpreting this as a phrase? It's two words with two separate meanings. You're overthinking it.

Comment: And underthinking it.

Comment: @Catija  So, it was poorly written?

Comment: Articles from the NYT are rarely poorly written. To "stand alone" is to be apart from a crowd. It can mean to be unequalled (meaning one is superior with no peers and so is singular), but that is not the case here. Clinton has endorsements around her and is therefore not "alone".  The key word for the meaning you're looking for is "alone".  Sanders is all by himself.

Comment: @Peter  How would be meaning be changed if "*is*" is used instead of "*stand*"?

Comment: Newspaper headlines are often deliberately punny.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment suggests, you have to take the meaning literally. For example, if there are 30 students in a classroom and 29 of them are seated and you are the only one who is standing, what will happen? You will be the only one "standing alone" and you will be noticed very well. This literal taking has evolved to mean "be unequaled" because if you are the only one who is doing something that is desirable, you are unequaled by your competitors as the below example sentence indicates:

> But Malaysia stands alone among the airlines flying here to score a
>   marvellous five stars for its economy class long haul seating.

If your example sentence is rephrased to the following, it would be easier to understand the literal meaning:

> Bernie Sanders stands by himself without any Senators who endorse him.
>   However, Hillary Clinton doesn't stand alone and she stands surrounded by
>   Senators who have endorsed her.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, to say he 'stands alone' is to say he is unsupported. The senators have not given Bernie their support; they aren't 'standing behind him' or 'standing with him'. If a group of people 'stand together' they are all supporting one-another.

In a general context, to 'stand alone' is to be without any support or backing - whatever task someone is trying to accomplish, they are doing it alone. The definition you found is a related, yet different, use for the phrase, but it doesn't fit here. For example, one could say 'Company XYZ stands alone in computer research breakthroughs' to use that definition. In that sentence, XYZ is 'unequaled' since no other groups are helping to make breakthroughs.

The use of the word 'stand' comes from it being traditionally linked to the image of being strong and brave in the face of a threat - literally standing up when facing an issue instead of running or hiding away. For example an army of ants could 'stand together' against a larger, dangerous insect, even though they are not literally standing as a human would.

Thus Bernie 'stands alone' when none of the senators support him in his efforts, or company XYZ 'stands alone' when figuring out computer research problems since no other company is figuring out the problems.

It's also worth noting that Bernie is often portrayed as an outcast or irregular presidential-candidate, so a reporter may think language that gives the feeling of 'fighting alone against adversity' is fitting when discussing Bernie.

The article is trying to say, in brief, that all of the senators are giving their support to Hillary, and none have supported Bernie.